Strange Python issue
I use Win 10, I was trying to connect Python to Arduino using serial.Serial, and it gave an attribute error. I think this error is fixed, but now it says:
Also, Arduino doesn't connect, I am in serious trouble, and I am thankful to whomever helps me.
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600) # Replace 'COM3' with the appropriate serial port on your computer               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 33, in __init__     super(Serial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__     self.open()   File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 64, in open     raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError())) serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2) PS C:\Users\hp> 

I would appreciate quick response.
the code:

import serial 

import time

arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

time.sleep(2) 

arduino.write('Hello Arduino!') 
time.sleep(0.2)
arduino.close() 


please i need an answer

It says:
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
As you did not confirm whether COM4 is the correct port on your system for your connected Arduino: Is it?
And if it is, close any other tool having the port open, e.g. the monitor part of Arduino IDE.

ill try right now

i changed it com 6 and still dosent work and thanks for the response

and huge thanks for early response

I found out the issue I just needed to close Serial monitor of Arduino IDE. It is a simple fix but I couldn't find it anywhere. I found it accidently.
Thank you for anyone who responded.
